# Checkbox value wrong behavior on buefy

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bulma, buefy

I generate a list of checkboxes from an array, and when I select some of the box, the v-model value (a generated array declared when Vue instance is created) doesn't add the new box value to the array but replace empty the array and place the value in it.

With an example : I got 3 values "Cat", "Dog" and "Bird". When I check "Cat", the array looks like that ["Cat"] and when I check "Dog" with "Cat", the array looks like that ["Dog"].

When I use a variable (array) defined in the data it works, but when I use my array in the form variable it doesn't work.

```html
<div id="root">
  <b-checkbox
      v-for="(field, key) in query.fields"
      v-model="form[query.id+'-'+query.priority]"
      :native-value="field.id">
      {{ field.name }}
  </b-checkbox>
</div>
```

```js
<script>
const vue = new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    data: {
        query: {id: 1, priority: 1, fields: [{id: 1, name: 'cat'}, {id: 2, name: 'dog'}, {id: 3, name: 'bird'}]),
        form: {},
    },
    created: function () {
        this.form[this.query.id+'-'+this.query.priority] = [];
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: `form` is an object (`form: {},` in `data`) so the `v-model` behaves like an object, not like an array. What do you expect? Should Vue change it to an array automatically? Also `this.form[this.query.id+'-'+this.query.priority] = [];` will only change the object inside the `form` object, not `form` itself.

Comment: `form` has more properties in it, I just no post the entire object for the example. I want `form` to behave like an object, but I don't understand why my generated array in it doesn't take all the checked boxes but juste the last one after each selection

Comment: That's because `v-model` will behave differently for arrays and objects. Here is a side-by-side comparison: https://jsfiddle.net/6p158thy/

Comment: I fork your example to match what I'm triying to explain https://jsfiddle.net/3x7wLv4t/

Comment: What's the point of using `v-model` as an object which contains an array instead of using an array as `v-model` to begin with? You can always use multiple `v-model`s and combine them in an object with a computed property if needed.

Comment: I'm using an object because I need to generate an undefined number of checkox groups which each is link to an input, and I need to defined an id to retrieve them. So I can't use an array for each group unless it's in an object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the behaviour of my object, I transformed it into an array using the id of the query as the id of the form. I fetch the priority of the query elsewhere.

It solves my problem but not the problem of using a string as an index for this kind of code.

```html
<div id="root">
  <b-checkbox
      v-for="(field, key) in query.fields"
      v-model="form[query.id]"
      :native-value="field.id">
      {{ field.name }}
  </b-checkbox>
</div>

<script>
const vue = new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    data: {
        query: {id: 1, priority: 1, fields: [{id: 1, name: 'cat'}, {id: 2, name: 'dog'}, {id: 3, name: 'bird'}]),
        form: [],
    },
    created: function () {
        this.form[this.query.id] = [];
    }
});
</script>
```